# How to throw an exception in a Promise catch block? (Unhandled promise rejection)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

I have a multiple functions that return a Promise. In case of an error they use `reject`. But I want to handle the errors in the catch block of `Promise.all()` call. But when running it causes an `Unhandled promise rejection`.

```
function errorFunc() {
    return new Promise((_, reject) {
    reject('rejected in errorFunc')
  })
}

Promise.all([
    errorFunc(),
]).catch(reasons => {
    //throw new Error('an error occured', reasons)
  console.log('an error occured')
})
```

As you can see the `console.log` works fine, but running when throwing an exception it fails.
I have read multiple articles and threads on unhandled promise rejection but I have not found a solution to that problem.

Here is the failing code on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkptbjnz/1/

How do I solve this issue? Or do you have a suggestion for a better error handling?

**Edit** I want to achieve some kind of validation like here: https://jsfiddle.net/89d5nLcw/

Comment: What's your goal here? You can handle the error in `catch` which is the intended way. No need to rethrow the error

Comment: @JensV I have a "validateObject" functions which calls multiple other validation functions asynchronously. When everythings done I want to throw an exception if one of them failed.

Comment: @JensV https://jsfiddle.net/89d5nLcw/ this is kind of the idea

Comment: It works just like with `try`/`catch`: when you re-`throw` an exception from the `catch` block, you will have to catch that again somewhere else, or your program crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should not throw an error in catch section, this block is designed to handle the errors.

```js
function errorFunc() {
    return new Promise((_resolve, reject) => {
    reject('rejected in errorFunc');
  });
}

Promise.all([
  errorFunc(),
]).catch(error => {
 console.log('an error occured', error);
})
```

like here you can see the message you threw above.

Comment: Yes that works but my handling of errors lays a layer above. What I try is to run multiple validation functions and catch all errors in a simple way. And after that, if any errors occured, I want to throw another error. Jus printing would continue the program although error occured here.

Comment: This is closer to what I want to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/89d5nLcw/

Comment: ok, im not sure, seems like you kinda try to catch the same error twice for some reason. `Promise.all` will throw an error if something happened, u dont have to catch it instantly. just make sure your "layer above" will catch it, and thats all.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I guess I'll have to rethink my structure.

Comment: well. all i can add is you dont need to catch the error to rethrow it again. just dont catch it until u need it =)